# Unable to assert ActionResult which returns jsonresult in Xunit

Tags: c#, assert, xunit, actionresult, jsonresult

I'm trying to assert an IActionResult which returns a JsonResult. I'm unable to access the IActionResult Values.

How can I do that?

[image]

UPDATE

This is the code.

```
[Fact]
    public async void AppendEmailTemplateUrl_ReturnOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<EmailController>>();
        var mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        var mockEmsWorkUnit = new Mock<IEmsWorkUnit>();
        var mockAzureBlob = new Mock<IAzureBlob>();

        // Setup
        var userRequestTemplateString = File.ReadAllText(@".\EmailController\UserRequestTemplate.txt");
        mockAzureBlob.Setup(blob => blob.GetHtmlBlob(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Uri>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(userRequestTemplateString);

        var emailController = new EmailController(mockLogger.Object, mockMapper.Object, mockEmsWorkUnit.Object, mockAzureBlob.Object);
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@".\EmailController\TemplateUrlOk.json");
        var testEmailUrlDto = GeneralHelpers.Deserialize<EmailUrlDto>(jsonString);

        // Act
        var result = await emailController.AppendEmailTemplateUrl(testEmailUrlDto);

        // Assert

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `JsonResult.Value` back to the known type to be formatted and perform your assertions on that

```
//...omitted for brevity

// Act
IActionResult result = await emailController.AppendEmailTemplateUrl(testEmailUrlDto);

//Assert
var actual = result as JsonResult;
Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
var model = actual.Value as ApiResult;
Assert.IsNotNull(model);

//...assert model
```

Also refactor the test to use `async Task` and not `async void`

```
[Fact]
public async Task AppendEmailTemplateUrl_ReturnOk() {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: would you be able to explain why async Task and not async void? would this will have any impact on those tests? :)